# Sort search results using interesting questions scoring algorithm

Tags: feature-request, search, interesting-page

The start page with its list of *interesting* questions does a very good job in *ordering* questions. The custom searches, on the other hand, provide very flexible ways to *select* questions. I'd be happy if there was some way to integrate these two: Use a custom search to specify *which* questions to display, and then apply the same [algorithm](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) which is used for the start page to decide *in what order* the results should be displayed.

My idea is that I might make the resulting search a bookmark, and likely use this as my main entry point into SO. As I assume others might use it in the same fashion, it might make sense to somehow store a combination of search and ordering and make that the default homepage for SO. For logged-in users only, of course, as otherwise it would be hard to store that information.